# Problem with converted ASCII value in android

Tags: android, hex, data-conversion, non-ascii-characters

I have Multiple Hex Value.

```
 String arr[] = {"4544582F3032313230362331383035350000000000000000000000000000",
            "4544582F3032313230362331383035350000000000000000000000000000",
            "300833B2DDD9014000000000",
            "300833B2DDD9014000000000",
            "300833B2DDD9014000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "4544582F3034353532312335353531300000000000000000000000000000",
            "4544582F3034353532312332353235380000000000000000000000000000",
            "4544582F3034323736322332353235380000000000000000000000000000",
            "4544582F3032313230362333373836390000000000000000000000000000",
            "4544582F3032313230362332353235380000000000000000000000000000",
            "4544582F3032313230362335353531300000000000000000000000000000"};
```

Conversion of HEX to ASCII code is:

```
for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr[k].length(); i += 2) {
            String str = arr[k].substring(i, i + 2);
            output.append((char) Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
        }
        textrfid.append(output + "\n");
        code[k] = output.toString();
    }
    Log.e("Data", textrfid.getText().toString());
```

When convert Hex to ASCII value the result in Log is :

```
EDX/021206#18055����������������������������
EDX/021206#18055����������������������������
3²ÝÙ@��������
3²ÝÙ@��������
3²ÝÙ@��������������������������������������������
EDX/045521#55510����������������������������
EDX/045521#25258����������������������������
EDX/042762#25258����������������������������
EDX/021206#37869����������������������������
EDX/021206#25258����������������������������
EDX/021206#55510����������������������������
```

I have used replace method for remove (�) sign but it's still showing.

**So Can you help me for removing the � symbol from value.**

Comment: It looks like every 0X00 is converted to a  � symbol . Instead of removing afterwards you better skip 0X00 values right away.

Comment: `if ( arr[k] == '0' && arr[k+1] == '0' ) continue;`

Comment: Or even: `if ( arr[k] == '0' && arr[k+1] == '0' ) break;`

Comment: where put this condition inner loop?

Comment: You are converting the values right, but sometimes on conversion that characters that you get is not Android-Studio_readable.

Comment: @SagarBalyan its showing every time when i convert that value

Comment: Try converting a simple hex first. Like just try with the hex `65`

Comment: @SagarBalyan Simple hex working properly. Issue occured with above defined hex only

Comment: I converted first item and got this: `EDX/021206#18055`

Comment: have to see that value on textview or Log??    Because on textview it is showing proper, but on log it shwing EDX/021206#18055 with append of � .